Tailwind doesn't render font-size with arbitrary value
I am trying to scale a span element based on a number from a variable:
export default async function Tags() {
  const tags = await getTags();

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
          {tags.results?.map((tag) => (
            <span
              key={tag.id}
              className={`pr-4 text-[${tag.font}px]`}
            >
              {tag.name}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

It creates desired output if I inspect the page:
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <span class="pr-4 text-[17px]">cars</span>
  <span class="pr-4 text-[18px]">sports</span>
  ...
</div>

But it doens't show on the page. If I replace ${tag.font} with a number it works, but not with the variable. What am I doing wrong?
UPDATE
It seems that only certain numbers work like 20 and 36, but now all of them. Why is that?

hi, you should show what css you have also, or name of any library if using

we're deinfately going to need to see the payload to help you out there, at a guess some values are missing or have an artefact like maybe a traillng space, but thats wild guessing until we see the data you're trying to work with.

@Max tailwind css

@danielRICADO I checked, the problem is not in Next.js. If the value of the variable is 20, then the font renders bigger. But if the value is 17 or 18 or 19 or 21, it renders as default 16, even though the class says text-[17px] when I  inspect it in dev tools.

Ricos answer is good, sometimes it's just better to go back to basics.

The reason it's not working is because of this:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS.

Dynamic class names in Tailwind
The reason 20 and 36 could be working is because you have those somewhere else in your codebase and TailwindCSS is generating those classes.
When working with Tailwind and you need to style an element based on some dynamic data, you should use the style tag.
{tags.results?.map((tag) => (
    <span
        key={tag.id}
        className="pr-4"
        style={{fontSize: `${tag.font}px`}}
    >
        {tag.name}
    </span>
))}

